# "Materialize" light sources and material from MatCap or Studio viewport shading

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, light, matcaps

I know MapCap and Studio viewport shading is only for previewing the model, not for the final rendering. But let's say I accidentally run into a lighting condition I like in MapCap:

[image]

Is it possible to "materialize" this MapCap setting, a.k.a. make the lights, materials and textures that will be rendered as such in EEVEE or Cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matcap files themselves (.exr files) are stored in the Blender folder at `.../2.93/datafiles/studiolights/matcap`. However, you can see that even if I apply it as an Environment Texture in the World Shader, the results are still slightly different to the MatCap look - probably meaning you will need some of your own lights as well:

Matcap in Solid Preview:
[image: Mat1]

MatCap as an Environment Texture
[image: Mat2]

Here it is with the environment "corrected" to show only the lighting and reflections from the "matcap" texture (more similar to the preview.) You can see that although close, it is still not the same. Changing the View Transform from *filmic* to *standard* helps, but it's not perfect.
[image: Mat3]

Comment: How does MatCap's lighting work? I tried to add my own light to mimic its behaviour, but it's so confusing. How is it well lit regardless of my camera angle?